# Extract Current Date and assign to variable in FTP Scripter (Pascal Environment)

Tags: ftp, pascal

I am using FTP Scripter (Base - Pascal) to create some scripts.
I have a requirement to create the folders based on current date.
Below is my code :-

```
var
  mydate: String;
  today : TDateTime;
  LocalArchive: String;
  
begin
  today := Now;
  mydate := FormatDateTime('ddmmyyyy', today);
  LocalArchive := 'D:\FOR TPA Archive\' + date;
end;
```

While compiling the above code, I am getting below error. PFB the screenshot for the same.
[image]

Can someone please help in fixing the above error.
I am using FTP Scripter which comes with Syncplify Software.

Thanks

Comment: It should be `LocalArchive := 'D:\FOR TPA Archive\' + mydate;`, not `date;`.  'Date' is a built-in function that returns today's date, as a TDateTime

Comment: @DavidA Thanks for pointing out. It worked. Sorry My bad.